# C# how to insert data in SQL table and setting an empty string into 0

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using this sql code to insert data into a table

```
"INSERT INTO electric VALUES('" + date.Text + "', '" + h1.Text + "', '" + h2.Text + "', '" + h22.Text + "', '" + h3.Text + "', '" + h4.Text + "', '" + h5.Text + "', '" + h6.Text + "', '" + h7.Text + "', '" + h8.Text + "', '" + h9.Text + "', '" + h10.Text + "');"
```

Sometimes I leave some TextBoxes empty and they are all int. but it won't insert into the table.
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjwEz.png)
I set the column default into 0 but still wont insert.
[default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEJ6P.png)

please help me to solve this problem.
thanks

Comment: Learn to use parameters rather than munging query strings.

Comment: The ideal way would be to use parameterize query or use proper casting. In your case column is an integer and you are passing ' ' value which is causing cast error. Assigning default value mean if you don't pass that column in your insert it will create a row with that column value as default. 0.

Comment: so if I used the parameter and it got a null value will it set to default which is 0 
@VivekShah

Comment: yes while assigning values do a proper cast or create dynamic sqls.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
    String query = "INSERT INTO electric (h1, h2, h3, h4) VALUES (@h1, @h2, @h3, @h4)";

    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
       int h1Data = 0;
       Int32.TryParse(h1TextBox.Text, out h1Data);

       int h2Data = 0;
       Int32.TryParse(h2TextBox.Text, out h2Data);

       int h3Data = 0;
       Int32.TryParse(h3TextBox.Text, out h3Data);

       int h4Data = 0;
       Int32.TryParse(h4TextBox.Text, out h4Data);

       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h1", h1Data);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h2", h2Data);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h3", h3Data);
       command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h4", h4Data);

       connection.Open();
       int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

       // Check Error
       if(result < 0)
       {
          // Error
       }
    }
}
```

**Explain :**

The textBoxs should be ints as you said so if not the error occurs !

Now it is easy, we create int var and get textBox content into it .. by default the int var equal zero and we use tryParse if textBox content isn't number, the conversion wouldn't be completed but the int var still have the default value which is zero and will be inserted into database (the same occurs with empty textBox or empty string).

You may need to edit it to work exactly as you want,

I hope it helps you .. good luck !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your help for me. the code works.

Comment: the problem is still the same. I tried to change Int32.TryParse into Convert.toInt32 and it didnt work also. I tried many methods I could think of but still not working @EssamMohamed

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to store empty string ('') to int field. Default value will be used only if you skip field from the list to insert.

In other word you need to cast values to integer when you concatenate a query. I am not familiar with C# but from brief search it probably can be done with [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks for the help.